# Paper that specifies how to define number ranges inside the ECC with varying equations

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves

I am looking for a textbook or published paper that provides specific information on how to configure an ECC. I came across it several years ago and now cannot find it. Does anyone know the source? Specifically, it talked about how to define number ranges inside the ECC with varying equations.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228565749_ELLIPTIC_CURVES_ARISING_FROM_NUMERICAL_RANGES

Comment: You could try the side channel chat first for questions like these, we don't necessarily want to plaster the front page with any possible question on where to find a paper that we cannot find immediately.